# Webpage displaying deleted code

Tags: php, html, href

This is the second time I'm having this weird problem.
I have a php page with some code.

Example:

```
<div id ="searchbg">
<form action="" method="post"></form>
</div>
```

Now when I delete the code and run the page, the deleted code still shows up.

I thought there maybe some problem with my browser(chrome) so I opened up the same page in Firefox but the same thing happens there too.  How can this happen? How to fox this? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: 1) You probably didn't delete it, or forgot to push your changes or something. 2) Possibly the cache, but if you switched browsers this is unlikely.

Comment: Did you try to press ctrl + F5 to rekord without cache

Comment: Could also be a server-side cache.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? This happened to me a few times with netbeans. If you are, restart the ide and see if the code is still there

Comment: Are you working on localhost or uploading to remote server? Are you on a home network or behind a proxy.

Comment: working on localhost. Home network

Comment: What program are you using to edit the php file?

Comment: Shure you made å clean refresh ( ctrl + F5) or just F5 or browser refresh button

Comment: restart apache / xampp

Comment: I have restarted it thrice. Yes I did a clean refresh using Ctrl + F5. I am using sublime text

Comment: Restart sublime and make shure files are realy saved where you want them